# How to hide tooltip bubble when modal dialog is closed

Tags: lightning

I have a modal dialog, on which I have some fields, two buttons [close, save]
I have included a tooltip on one of the fields

```
<div class="modal-static-column">
  <lightning:helptext content="{!$Label.c.HelpText}"/>
</div>
```

When the mouse hovers over the tooltip icon, the bubble text is shown.
The bubble text remains when the following sequence of events occurs

- give focus to one of the fields
- hover the mouse over tooltip icon (bubble text appears)
- use keyboard TAB key to navigate focus to the [Cancel] button
- ensuring the bubble help text is still visible hit the return key

The modal dialog closes, but the tooltip bubble text still shows.

How can I clear the bubble text?

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

Add an aura:id to the div (preferably) or the lightning:helptext like so:

```
<div aura:id="hideAfterClose" class="modal-static-column">
  <lightning:helptext content="{!$Label.c.HelpText}"/>
</div>
```

And in the method responsible for closing the modal, hide the div via CSS:

```
onClose: function(cmp, event) {
        var helpText = cmp.find('hideAfterClose');
        $A.util.addClass(helpText, 'slds-hide');
    },
```

Comment: That will hide the tooltip icon itself, but it won't get rid of the popup bubble text

    `<lightning-primitive-bubble style="position: absolute; min-width: 75px; left: 533px; bottom: 668.5px;" class="slds-popover slds-popover_tooltip slds-nubbin_bottom-left slds-rise-from-ground">`

onClose needs to be able to get at this DOM element and replace `slds-rise-from-ground` with `slds-fall-into-ground`.

But, I don't know how to get at this element?